# Wordpress can't acces Login page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, authentication, wp-admin

I copied my web to live host, but when I try to access the admin dashboard the URL can't be accessed.

This is the url redirection:
http://backstagewhisp.local/wp-admin/backstagewhisp.local/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fbackstagewhisp.local%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

I also changed the .htacces file to be like this, but the error is still showing:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ 
http://backstagewhisp.local/$4
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /home/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /home/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can someone give me advice to fix my error? Thanks.

Comment: You need to point DNS with your Host IP

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems with your base url, which is `backstagewhisp.local`. 
Please check wp-config or other settings where you have defined your base url.